# Spring batch integration using OutBoundGateway and ReplyingKafkaTemplate

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration, spring-kafka

**My Goal**
I need to read a file and divide each line as a message and send to kafka from a spring batch project and another spring integration project will be receiving the messages to process it in a **async** way. I want to return those messages after processing to the batch project and create 4 different files out of those messages.

Here I am trying to use *OutBoundGateway* and *ReplyingKafkaTemplate*. I am unable to configure it properly... Is there any example or reference guide to configure it.

I have checked spring batch integration samples github repository... There is no sample for outBoundGateway or ReplyingKafkaTemplate.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `ReplyingKafkaTemplate` logic in Spring Integration there is a dedicated `KafkaProducerMessageHandler` which can be configured with a `ReplyingKafkaTemplate`.

See more info in docs:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/kafka.html#kafka-outbound-gateway

And more about `ReplyingKafkaTemplate`:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#replying-template

Probably on the other a `KafkaInboundGateway` must be configured, respectively:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/kafka.html#kafka-inbound-gateway

Comment: Actually I was following other links... thanks for https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#replying-template link. Will try to implement and let you know...

Comment: Right, but Spring Integration provides more smooth support for that pattern: a lot of stuff is handled on your behalf.

Comment: Can you please point any particular resource to learn about the spring integration?

Comment: Just go from its official page: https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration